# how can I do this hibernate mapping?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

To acquaint with the issue...

I have a group of tables related with a specific table. now for doing the relation between all of them and the "table_one" I made only a table which has as primary key composed by:

id_table_one, id_table_many, id_table_many_type.

The first one indicates the id of the table_one, the second the id of the table_many (any of them) and the third key is a string which indicates the type of the table.

An example to be more specific:

1, 1, "table 1" -> indicates the relation between the table_many "table 1" (row 1) with the row 1 of the table_one

3, 5, "table 1" -> indicates the relation between the table_many "table 1" (row 5) with the row 3 of the table_one

3, 5, "table 2" -> indicates the relation between the table_many "table 2" (row 5) with the row 3 of the table_one

This is easy to do in SQL, but the question is, how can I do the hibernate mapping in each table_many?

I declared the table_one as follows:

```
<class name="tableOne" table="table_one">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="idTableOne"  type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_table_one" not-null="true"/>
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="idTableMany"  type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_table_many" not-null="true"/>
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="idTableManyType" type="string">
            <column name="id_table_many_type" length="100" not-null="true"/>
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
</class>
```

How can I do the  into the many tables?

```
<class name="tableMany1" table="table_many_1">
    <id name="idTableMany1" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id_table_many_1" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <set cascade="all" name="tableOneRows" sort="unsorted"
        table="table_one"  lazy="false">
        <...>
    </set>
</class>
```

I don't know how to fill in the <...> section...any advice?

The finality I am pursuing is to manage the tableOne (read/write) from each tableMany...

thx all!

Answer (score 0):

this is for reading only

```
  <class name="One" table="table_one">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
    </id>
  </class>

  <class name="Many1" table="table_many_1">
    <id name="id">
      <column name="id_table_many_1" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <set cascade="all" name="Ones" table="linking_table" lazy="false" where="id_table_many_type = 'table 1'">
      <key column ="id_table_many" />
      <many-to-many column="d_table_one" class="One" />
    </set>
  </class>
```

the writepart depends on: is table_one to table_many1 a 1:n or n:m association?